# What are the constraints on how loose a comment can be?

Tags: discussion

I know that Answers have to remain on-topic and relevant to the question, as well as attempt to answer the question asked. I'm not entirely clear on the boundaries on comments though. For example, [in this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68766/geforce-gtx1070-supported-or-not) I answer the question fully, however afterwards I have kindof a casual mini-discussion with the OP (the discussion remains on-topic). Is this behavior fine or would it be better if I avoid interacting with people like this?

Comment: Yes, discussion and social conversation are great! The only thing is to consider moving it to a chat room if a particular discussion is getting lengthy with no sign of slowing down. This keeps the comment section tidy and allows other comments to be more visible. (There should be a prompt to do this automatically after a certain number of comments have been exchanged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are disposable. Small conversations are probably fine, however, the comments are not a chat room. If there are more useful comments, the ones with upvotes will stay, while the ones without upvotes may be deleted

Comment: Comments don't get deleted based on their votes... the person commenting can delete his/her own comments. Else they can be flagged so that moderators can intervene. Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/following-a-thread-sequence-when-edited/1104#1104